# vNext Build and Release Manager

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

We are using TFS 2015. I'd like to create a build and then trigger a release (with RM). We have a webproject and a wpf app. Inside of the code we have compiler directives (#if DEBUG). And the config transformation has to be executed.

My approach was to create a build for Debug and Release, publish it and copy it to a drop folder. 
Can anyone tell me what is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trigger an agent-based release, you can use a custom build task:

https://github.com/incyclesoftware/build-tasks

(Full disclosure: I created these tasks.)

When you deploy a task-based build, make sure the component in Release Management is named the same thing as the artifact you published in the build.

Comment: Cool stuff Daniel! :)