# Release Management 2015 with TFS 2015 Build vNext

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, release, ms-release-management

We are trying to use Release Management for Visual Studio 2015 and Team Foundation Server 2015 to build and eventually deploy from our Code System to our QA System.

We have defined 2 different types of builds in TFS 2015 (The new scriptable build Definition – Team Foundation Build and XAML definition):

We are able to queue both these definitions and they build successfully.

Next when we go to Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2015 and create a new Release, after selecting the Release Template, it allows us to select a Build. Searching these Builds returns only the builds from the XAML definitions and not from the Team Foundation Build ones.

How do we get Release Management to use the builds from Team Foundation Builds?

Comment: OK we believe we figured it out. We have to use the vNext Release Templates to enable the new Build Definitions

Answer (score 1):

To release them automatically,

**For the XAML build system**, make sure to copy the release template (named similarly to ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml ) to your BuildProcessTemplates from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Release Management\Client\bin" and use it as the Process Template for your release build.

**For the new scriptable build system**, you will also need to either run a Command Line task that executes ReleaseManageBuild.exe (found in the same folder as above) with some supplied arguments ( more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/release-management-continuous-deployment-with-visual-studio-online-and-any-ci-systems.aspx ).

Or, you can use the tasks found in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32994949/3317095
I have not personally tested Daniel Mann's task, but it looks very similar to the one I made for myself and I incorporated some of his code into mine. And let's be honest, he's the subject matter expert in this area.

Comment: Thanks for the plug; I've used the tasks for a few customers and they work. Plus, I haven't gotten a single angry email about it not working, so I'm pretty sure they work.